# Use masterpage CSS and JavaScript in ASP form child-page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a master page which containing few CSS links and java scripts.

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">`

```
<script src="Scripts/slides.min.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
       <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#pikame").PikaChoose();

            });
       </script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

`

I want to use this JavaScript and css style files ,in child ASP form page which has inherited from above master page.

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" asterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LeadInformation.aspx.cs" Inherits="LeadInformation" %>`

`<%@ MasterType TypeName="MasterPage" %>`

Seems this way not working. Please anyone help me to use masterpage CSS and JavaScript in child-page to me. Tx in advanced.

Comment: asterPageFile is that a typo in the question or in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script outside the `ContentPlaceHolder` tag. Just put it in the `head` section normally.

The `ContentPlaceHolder` tag should be empty in the Master Page - its contents will be replaced by the `asp:Content` tags in the Pages.

You can check if it's being rendered properly by browsing to the page and right-click -> View Source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
```

is used to provide script,css that are specific to only that child page

so if you want the scripts/css to be applied to the child pages just place it normally in the master page head section and outside head `ContentPlaceHolder` in master page..

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

First, child pages are not inherited from master pages. It's the same page.
Second, you don't need MasterType directive to access javascript.

So just consider masterpage and child page to be one as it will be one page when it renders to Browser and javascript runs on browser. So you can place your javascript/CSS anywhere in the head section of master page and access it from any of the child page in a same manner as they are on the same page.